# SSRS CASE based on parameter selection to then pass Select statement

Tags: sql, select, reporting-services, parameter-passing, case

I have a SSRS report with a parameter with 3 options

1. Customers = All
2. Customers = A (more than 1 customer)
3. Customers = All - A

Based on selection I want the SQL to be

```
Case 2
 Select * from customers where customer in (A)
Case 3
 Select * from customers where customer not in (A)
Else
 Select * from customers
```

My parameter is:
[image: [![Select * from customers where customer not in (A)][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWZoU.png]

And my select statements are currently:

```
    select t.Docket, t.TranType, Convert(Date,t.Despatchdatetime) as DespatchDate, t.Depot, t.Plant, t.Product, p.ProductName, t.Gross, t.Net, t.Tare, t.Vehicle, t.Rego, p.ProductName + ' ' + t.Docket as TEXT, T.Vehicle + ' ' + T.Rego as [Field Assignment], t.Customer + ' ' + t.CustomerName as Customer
    from trans t, product p
    where t.depot in (@Depot)
    and t.plant in (@Plant)
    and t.DespatchDateTime >= (@DespatchFrom) and t.despatchDateTime <= (@DespatchTo)
    and p.Product = t.product
    and t.cancelleddocket = '0'
    and t.trantype <> 'DIV'
**  and t.customer [Depending on parameter selection]
    Order by t.plant, t.despatchdatetime,t.docket
```

But I can't seem to get the statement right:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN Parameters!Customers.Value='Exclude' then 
                        (    select t.Docket, t.TranType, Convert(Date,t.Despatchdatetime) as DespatchDate, t.Depot, t.Plant, t.Product, p.ProductName, t.Gross, t.Net, t.Tare, t.Vehicle, t.Rego, p.ProductName + ' ' + t.Docket as TEXT, T.Vehicle + ' ' + T.Rego as [Field Assignment], t.Customer + ' ' + t.CustomerName as Customer
                from trans t, product p
                where t.depot in (@Depot)
                and t.plant in (@Plant)
                and t.DespatchDateTime >= (@DespatchFrom) and t.despatchDateTime <= (@DespatchTo)
                and p.Product = t.product
                and t.cancelleddocket = '0'
                and t.trantype <> 'DIV'
                and t.customer not in ('123','456')
                Order by t.plant, t.despatchdatetime,t.docket )
            
        WHEN Parameters!Customers.Value='ABL' then 
                        (select t.Docket, t.TranType, Convert(Date,t.Despatchdatetime) as DespatchDate, t.Depot, t.Plant, t.Product, p.ProductName, t.Gross, t.Net, t.Tare, t.Vehicle, t.Rego, p.ProductName + ' ' + t.Docket as TEXT, T.Vehicle + ' ' + T.Rego as [Field Assignment], t.Customer + ' ' + t.CustomerName as Customer
                from trans t, product p
                where t.depot in (@Depot)
                and t.plant in (@Plant)
                and t.DespatchDateTime >= (@DespatchFrom) and t.despatchDateTime <= (@DespatchTo)
                and p.Product = t.product
                and t.cancelleddocket = '0'
                and t.trantype <> 'DIV'
                and t.customer in ('123','456')
                Order by t.plant, t.despatchdatetime,t.docket )
        
                ELSE 
                        (select t.Docket, t.TranType, Convert(Date,t.Despatchdatetime) as DespatchDate, t.Depot, t.Plant, t.Product, p.ProductName, t.Gross, t.Net, t.Tare, t.Vehicle, t.Rego, p.ProductName + ' ' + t.Docket as TEXT, T.Vehicle + ' ' + T.Rego as [Field Assignment], t.Customer + ' ' + t.CustomerName as Customer
                from trans t, product p
                where t.depot in (@Depot)
                and t.plant in (@Plant)
                and t.DespatchDateTime >= (@DespatchFrom) and t.despatchDateTime <= (@DespatchTo)
                and p.Product = t.product
                and t.cancelleddocket = '0'
                and t.trantype <> 'DIV'
                Order by t.plant, t.despatchdatetime,t.docket )
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  select t.Docket, t.TranType, Convert(Date,t.Despatchdatetime) as DespatchDate, t.Depot, t.Plant, t.Product, p.ProductName, t.Gross, t.Net, t.Tare, t.Vehicle, t.Rego, p.ProductName + ' ' + t.Docket as TEXT, T.Vehicle + ' ' + T.Rego as [Field Assignment], t.Customer + ' ' + t.CustomerName as Customer
                from trans t
                join product p ON p.Product = t.product
                where t.depot in (@Depot)
                and t.plant in (@Plant)
                and t.DespatchDateTime >= (@DespatchFrom) and t.despatchDateTime <= (@DespatchTo) 
                and t.cancelleddocket = '0'
                and t.trantype <> 'DIV'
                and (( @Customers = 'Exclude' and t.customer not in ('123','456') )
                    OR(@Customers='ABL' AND t.customer in ('123','456') )
                    OR @Customers='ALL'
                    )
                Order by t.plant, t.despatchdatetime,t.docket )
```

Comment: Thank you @freedom!